# How to create new parent child gamobjects at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a button click two new gameObjects are created and the second one is setting as a child of first one and first one is child of attached object. But it is not working / showing on hierarchy but the created object is not appearing in game window.

Here is the code:

```
public void CreateTextButtonClick(string text)
{
    Debug.Log("Hey starting of this..");
    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText");
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);


    GameObject pan = new GameObject("text");
    pan.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = pan.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = Color.blue;


    //image
    //GameObject back = new GameObject("image");
    //back.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform);

    //Image i = back.AddComponent<Image>();

    Debug.Log("Hey its done..");

}
```

What can be a solution to achieve this multi level object making?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'not working'? what exactly is your error?

Comment: Its not showing the object.

Comment: Really not a good way to ask a question. If we don't understand your problem, we really can't help. "not working" = not showing in the GameView? Not showing in the Hierarchy tab? Error?

Comment: showing on hierarchy but the created object is not appearing in game window.

Answer (score 2):

You used `SetParent` properly in the first Object you want to be child of your Canvas by passing `false` to it which causes it to keep its local orientation:

```
GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText");
txtObj.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);
```

But you *did **not** do this* for the "text" Object that will be child of the object above:

```
GameObject pan = new GameObject("text");
pan.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform);
```

You can fix that by also passing `false` to it so that the UI component to keep its local orientation. Unrelated but I also think you should add a `RectTransform` the parent object too. Add `RectTransform` to anything that will be under the Canvas.

Your new code:

```
public void CreateTextButtonClick(string text)
{
    Debug.Log("Hey starting of this..");
    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText");
    txtObj.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);

    GameObject pan = new GameObject("text");
    pan.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform, false);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = pan.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = Color.blue;
}
```

In your commented code, it looks like you plan to add another child object with `Image` component too and I can already see that mistake there. Do not forget to do this too. You must otherwise, you will have issues. This applies to everything you plan to place under the `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's appearing now. But for multiple button click the txtObj object with child is appearing at the same place, while the same object(without child) with     Text txt = txtObj.AddComponent<Text>(); follows vertical layout rules of its parents and appears in a top to bottom order. How can this be fixed so that this new created txtObj with child also follows that same top to bottom rule?

Comment: Well the not appearing issue is solve. You should create new question with screenshot of your setup. What is attached to what, what components you're suing and then finally the current look in the scene. Also show what you expect it to look like. Without these, you may not get an answer since people won't know the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Added a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51219934/how-to-make-new-gameobject-with-multiple-siblings-follow-its-parent-objects-layo) with screenshots.

Comment: It seems like your new issue is solve you have accepted the answer from the other question. If so then don't forget to accept this one. Happy coding!

Comment: The updated code is not exactly dynamic with height, so, can you please review the updated issue and give your opinion?