# How to make new GameObject with multiple siblings follow its parent objects layout rules?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The button click function attached to to a button will create new gameObjects and first one will be child of reference gameObject, the second one will be child of first one. The referenced object has vertical layout group attached but the created child is not following the order.

Here is the code that created new objects:

```
public void CreateTextButtonClick(GameObject panel)
{
    string text = "hello..";
    Debug.Log("Hey starting of this..");
    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText");
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);


    //image
    GameObject back = new GameObject("image");
    back.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform, false);

    Image i = back.AddComponent<Image>();

    //text
    GameObject pan = new GameObject("text");
    pan.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform, false);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = pan.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = Color.blue;

    Debug.Log("Hey its done..");

}
```

Here the child appears at the same place while it is expected to be from top to bottom order.

Heres the screenshot while not in play mode:

[image]

Here's the screenshot while in play mode and after two button clicks the object appeared on scrollViews panel but in unexpected way:

[image]

dragging this will reveal the object.

> And also objects with no child follows that layout rule.

---

How can that object be in a order that shows one after another also in properly within the view port?

---

Thanks.

---

Update:

With multiline strings, with  [Soragge]'s given code this will happen with height checkboxes checked :
[image]

with height checkboxes not checked:

[image]

Can this be made dynamic with more objects added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your new objects are missing the RectTransform. Try this:

```
GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText", typeof(RectTransform));
```

And if you want them to show starting from top, uncheck both Height checkboxes at the Layout Component.

**Edit:**
If you want the content to fit the text, keep the Height checkboxes checked and add the `ContentSizeFitter` component to the Content game object with `Vertical Fit` set to `Preferred Size`. The `txtObj` must also have a layout group attached. This should do the trick:

```
public void CreateTextButtonClick(GameObject panel)
{
    string text = "hello..";
    Debug.Log("Hey starting of this..");

    //Create Canvas Text and make it child of the Canvas
    GameObject txtObj = new GameObject("myText", typeof(RectTransform));
    txtObj.transform.SetParent(panel.transform, false);
    HorizontalLayoutGroup layoutgroup = txtObj.AddComponent<HorizontalLayoutGroup>();
    layoutgroup.childAlignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
    layoutgroup.childControlWidth = false;

    //image
    GameObject back = new GameObject("image");
    back.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform, false);
    back.AddComponent<LayoutElement>().ignoreLayout = true;
    Image i = back.AddComponent<Image>();
    RectTransform imageRectTransform = back.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    imageRectTransform.anchorMin = Vector2.zero;
    imageRectTransform.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
    imageRectTransform.sizeDelta = Vector2.zero;

    //text
    GameObject pan = new GameObject("text");
    pan.transform.SetParent(txtObj.transform, false);

    //Attach Text,RectTransform, an put Font to it
    Text txt = pan.AddComponent<Text>();
    txt.text = text;
    Font arialFont = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    txt.font = arialFont;
    txt.lineSpacing = 1;
    txt.color = Color.blue;

    Debug.Log("Hey its done..");
}
```

Comment: its working. But now the txtObj has a static width and height and is not expanding by default. What can be attached so that it expands as the content grows?

Comment: Do you want it to expand vertically? According to the size of the text?

Comment: I added a way to fit the content in the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But if checkboxes for height is checked it works for few objects added and shows it fully. But for more objects, with any long string it cuts off area of that gameObject and squeezes all into the viewPort. So I added similar RectTransform object to txt Component and uncheked the height checkBoxes. Its a temporary solution but now its height is not dynamic and limited to a fixed height of gameobjects. So, checking height squeezes all objects into the viewPort and with above my solution its not dynamic.

Comment: added results screenshot with and without height checked. Please see this.

Comment: Is this happening even with the Content Size Fitter?